# How do I stop/break execution when selection has been found in this jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I got help with the code below from you guys on forum and the code works perfectly, but client threw a curve ball.  How do I stop/break execution when selection has been found in this jquery code?  They want the same fieldset to display for a couple of project type selections. But since the code continues running it turns off the FS if the same 'sect_id' is appears.  How do I put in a **break**, so when it finds the matching value, it just stops searching?

```
$('fieldset#section-841', 'fieldset#section-837' ).hide();
    var DM_projtype = new Array(
        {value : 'Direct Mail', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-841'},
        {value : 'Multiples2-92', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-837'},
        {value : 'Multiples10+', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-837'}
    );
    $('select#3596').on('change',function() {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        var sect_id = '';
        $(DM_projtype).each(function()
        {
           $(this.sect_id).hide();
           if(this.value == thisValue)
               $(this.sect_id).show();
       });

   });
)
```

Comment: Please take care to properly indent code here.  It makes it far easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `return false`. See below,

```
   $(DM_projtype).each(function()
   {
       $(this.sect_id).hide();

       if(this.value == thisValue) {
          $(this.sect_id).show();
          return false; // will break out of loop
       }

   });
```

Comment: break is for javascript looping and $.each is a function even though it iterates. As suggested in jQuery docs, use `return false` to break out of `$.each`

Comment: I tried break as well with no results, so thank you for that explanation and the return false works - thanks again.